# Creating private chat in node js and unable to send message to particular socket id

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Below is my Server side and client side file:

Server side file:

```
'use strict';
var model = require('../model/model.js');

class Socket{
    constructor(socket){
        this.io = socket;
        this.users = [];
    }

    socketEvents(){ 
        this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            socket.on('username', (data) => {

                this.users.push({
                    id : socket.id,
                    userName : data.username
                });


                let len = this.users.length;
                len--;

                model.addSocketId( data.username,this.users[len].id);

                this.io.emit('userList',this.users,this.users[len].id); 
            });

            socket.on('getMsg', (data) => {
                model.insertMessages({
                        fromUserId: data.fromUserId,
                        toUserId: data.toUserId,
                        message: data.msg
                });
                console.log("socket id is:");
                console.log(data.toid);
                socket.broadcast.to(data.toid).emit('sendMsg',{
                    msg:data.msg,
                    name:data.name
                });

            });

            socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
                for(let i=0; i < this.users.length; i++){
                    if(this.users[i].id === socket.id){
                        this.users.splice(i,1); 
                    }
                }
                this.io.emit('exit',this.users); 
            });
        });
    }

    socketConfig(){
        this.socketEvents();
    }
}
module.exports = Socket;


Below is my Client Side File:

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.12:3000");

    socket.on('sendMsg', (data) => {
        console.log("send message-list");
        $('#message-list').append("<li class='friend-user'>"+data.msg+"</li>");
    });

    socket.on('userList', (completeUserList,userSocketId) => {
       console.log('userlist function');
       var userList = completeUserList;
    });

    $('document').ready(function(){
       $(document).on('click', "#msg-btn", function (event) {
       var messagePacket = {
            toid: $("#friendSocketId").text(),  //stored in hidden format from db 
            msg: $('#message').val(),
            name: $("#myUserName").text(),
            fromUserId: $("#loginUserId").text(),
            toUserId: $("#friendUserId").text(),
    };
    socket.emit('getMsg',messagePacket);
});


</script>
```

In this, When user clicks on send button from front-end then "getMsg" event emitting successfully. getMsg function took receiver socket id as message and emit "sendMsg" event to particular socket id. But sendMsg event is not sending msg to particular socket id. please help.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>It looks like you don't have a key called `toid` on `data` object. You might have mistyped it. Replace `toid` with `toUserId` and it should work.</s>

Since you are sending a message to another socket, instead of a room, you can use `socket.to().emit()` instead of `socket.broadcast.to()`.

From [Socket.IO docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room):

```
// a private message to another socket
socket.to(/* another socket id */).emit('hey');
```

So, replace `socket.broadcast.to()` with `socket.to().emit()`, like:

```
socket.to(data.toid).emit('sendMsg',{
                   msg:data.msg,
                   name:data.name
               });
```

**EDIT:**

You asked the following question in the comments below this answer:

> Does socket id changed automatically after
>   login when user send message or it remains same when client logged in?

Socket id is created for each client when `io.connect()` is executed.

In your code, this is the first line in your script file. So, a new socket id is created every time this script loads.

So, every time the page containing this script is loaded, a new socket id is created. If you refresh the page, this script loads again and a new socket id is created.

To answer your question, socket id remains same as long as user is on the same page. So, when a user sends a message it doesn't change, unless the user navigates to another page or refreshes this page after sending the message. So, if a user logs out and logs in, this page loads again, so socket id changes.

I think you are storing the socket id in database after user logs in, but are not updating it when user navigates to another page or logs out and logs in again. So, when you are emitting a message from server, you are sending it to user's previous socket id, not the current one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in console.log I m getting data.toid value and it is correct as stored in db for that particular user.

Comment: Okay! Try replacing `socket.broadcast.to().emit()` with `socket.to().emit()`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Still not working by using socket.to(data.toid).emit()

Comment: Okay, just to make sure, are you sending this message to the sender (the same socket which sent this message)?

Comment: No, I logged-in from one user on chrome browser and from second user on firefox and from third one in my mobile. I am trying to send private message from chrome user to firefox user. when i am using io.emit then it is visible on all 3 screens and if i am using socket.emit then it is visible to sender only. If am using socket.to(data.receiverSocketId).emit() then not receiving anywhere. I have one question here, does socket id changed automatically after login when user send message or it remains same when client logged in. Please read both my files again.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, As you suggest, now I'm updating socket id value in db when page reload by using socket.emit('userid', userid); in my client script file. And getting receiver updated socket ID from db when user send a msg to a particular person.